# CentOS: QtWebKit is missing and Anki won't start

Tags: python, qt, webkit, centos, pyqt4

I'm trying to run `anki` on CentOS and get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/anki", line 5, in <module>
    import aqt
  File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from aqt.qt import *
  File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/qt.py", line 13, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage, QWebView, QWebSettings
ImportError: No module named QtWebKit
```

I have installed the following packages:

```
qtwebkit-2.1.1-1.el6.i686
qtwebkit-2.1.1-1.el6.x86_64
qtwebkit-devel-2.1.1-1.el6.x86_64
```

but `Anki` still crashes.

I searched on forums and found that I need to check the place where Python searches for this module:

```
>>> import PyQt4
>>> print PyQt4.__path__
['/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/PyQt4']
```

In my case, this folder contains some `.so` files, but no `QtWebKit.so`.

I searched the filesystem for this file and found some matches, although I'm not sure it's what Python needs:

```
/usr/lib/libQtWebKit.so.4
/usr/lib/libQtWebKit.so.4.8.1
/usr/lib/libQtWebKit.so.4.8
/usr/lib64/libQtWebKit.so.4
/usr/lib64/libQtWebKit.so.4.8.1
/usr/lib64/libQtWebKit.so.4.8
```

How can I fix this problem?
Unfortunately I don't have permission to modify `/usr/lib64` folder, so I need to tell Python where to get required `.so` file from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the official CentOS PyQt4 packages don't include the QtWebKit module (not even in the latest release).

However, there do seem to be separate PyQt4 webkit packages available elsewhere. Probably the best way to get them is to add one of the [Community Approved Repositories](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) to yum.

The [Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL)](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) has the [PyQt4-webkit](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/PyQt4-webkit.html) package you want. Apparently, this repository is included with CentOS Extras, and should be enabled by default. But if it isn't, you can enable it with:

```
    yum install epel-release
```

And then do:

```
    yum install PyQt4-webkit
```

Comment: I managed to start it, but it crashes anyway a bit later. I have `qt-4.6.2` installed and it seems there is no newer version, because yum tells me `Package 1:qt-4.6.2-28.el6_5.x86_64 already installed and latest version`. Is it possible to upgrade it to 4.8 somehow?

Comment: @damluar. I downloaded the anki source, and the readme says you need at least version 4.7 of both qt and pyqt4, which is obviously later that what you currently have installed. There are ways to upgrade to later versions (see the first link in my answer), but I think that goes well beyond the scope of your original question. If you do a little web-searching I'm sure you will find plenty of guidance on the subject. The only advice I will give here is this: please research everything *very thoroughly* before making any further changes to your system.